# jQuery handler to know when at least 1 character has been typed into an input text element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple input like the following:

`<input type="text" id="foo">`

I tried using `change()` in order to detect when at least 1 character has been keyed in. The problem is, the event doesn't fire off until the input text box has lost focus.

Is there another event I can bind to and be able to trigger some code when at least 1 character has been typed?

Comment: keypress or keydown (depending on if you want to catch it before or after the character is inserted)

Comment: `is there any other event` .... not hard to research in a simple web search or in jQuery api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`keydown()`](https://api.jquery.com/keydown/). You can also try [`keypress()`](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/), which fires when the key is *down*, or [`keyup()`](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/), which is when the key is *lifted up*.

These all fire after a single key, not upon losing focus.

Therefore, you can try:

```js
$("#test").keydown(function() {
  $("#console").prepend(
    (($(this).val().length) ?
      "Not Empty" :
      "Empty")
    + "<br />"
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" />
<div id="console"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might give input a try.

```
$('#foo').on('input', function(){
    if (this.value.trim().length) {
        console.log('we got a char');
    }
});
```

Input is filtered to be thing that change the actual input of the element.  So you don't have to worry about random keys like function keys and stuff, enter press, etc.

Comment: note though that `input` event doesn't have older browser support and has quirks in IE9